# Reference to the field in the same/containing structure

Tags: rust

I've created this simple example to simulate what happens with references in my program.

```
struct Child {}

struct Parent<'a> {
    child: &'a Child
}

struct Family {
    child: Box<Child>,
    parents: Vec<Box<dyn Any>>
}

fn main() {
    let child = Box::new(Child {});
    let mut family = Family { child, parents: vec![] }; // child was moved to the family

    let parent = Box::new(Parent { child: &family.child }); // Parent accepts reference to family's child

    family.parents.push(parent); // Now parent was moved to the family.
    // So Family owns both: child and parent, 
    // so reference to the child in the parent will be correct during
    // lifetime of family
}
```

This code looks correct for me because the Family owns both: Child and Parent, so they will be dropped at the same time and the Parent can safely hold a reference to the child. But rust compiler doesn't think so:

```
error[E0597]: `family.child` does not live long enough
   |
18 |     let parent = Box::new(Parent { child: &family.child }); // Parent accepts reference to family's child
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
19 | 
20 |     family.parents.push(parent); // Now
   |                         ------ cast requires that `family.child` is borrowed for `'static`
21 | }
   | - `family.child` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Usage of `dyn Any` and boxes is intentional - it simulates what happens in my program.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) which has an excellent answer

Comment: I saw that question. Looks similar but I think it's not exactly this situation: I have different error, and referenced objects is stored in the heap rather than in stack as in suggested answer.

Comment: I was actually just editing my comment to say I see that you have a different error, so maybe it is not the same.

Comment: The linked answer specifically deals with how to work around the "overzealous" borrow-checker when your values are on the heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have two unrelated issues:

#### 1. `Parent` does not implement `dyn Any`

Despite the name, not every type implements the `Any` trait, as explained in the `std::any` [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html):

> Most types implement `Any`. However, any type which contains a non-`'static` reference does not.

So your `Parent` struct cannot implement `Any` (unless it is restricted to only have `'static` children). As you say the `dyn Any` comes from the rest of your program, it is difficult to advise a fix.

#### 2. Storing a value and a reference to that value in the same struct

This has been asked before and there is a [truly excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/8742505).

The usual problem with self-referential structs is that they cannot be moved without invalidating the references.

However, in some cases we **can** move a self-referential struct safely, such as when the referred-to values are `Box`ed (as in your `Family`) provided that the boxed values are never moved. The linked-to answer covers this case and lists possible workarounds.